# How to get links from google html search results in c#?

Tags: c#, html-parser

I got this code that brings me the search results from Google as an HTML string:

```
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
 string htmlString = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + searchQuery);
```

Any idea how to extract only the links from it ?
I guess I do a string search, but it doesn't look so elegant...

I found this code

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlString);
var selectNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@class='g']");
foreach (var node in selectNodes)
{
     //node.InnerText will give you the text content of the li tags ...
}
```

But I'm getting an exception that `var selectNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@class='g']");` is null...

Comment: you can use htmlagilitypack from here http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Can you please provide some code sample how to use it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load("file.htm");
        HtmlNodeCollection links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@background or @lowsrc or @src or @href]");
        foreach (HtmlNode link in links)
        {

            if (link.Attributes["background"] != null)
                link.Attributes["background"].Value = _newPath + link.Attributes["background"].Value;
            if (link.Attributes["href"] != null)
                link.Attributes["href"].Value = _newPath + link.Attributes["href"].Value;(link.Attributes["href"] != null)
                link.Attributes["lowsrc"].Value = _newPath + link.Attributes["href"].Value;
            if (link.Attributes["src"] != null)
                link.Attributes["src"].Value = _newPath + link.Attributes["src"].Value;
        }
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `_newPath` ?